# Getting all child names using xmlstarlet/xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Using xmlstarlet/xpath, how do I get the name of all child elements of a certain node? For example, I want to get all the child element names of `/a`

```
<a>
    <b><c/></b>
    <d/>
</a>
```

Should return:

```
b
d
```

I tried

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c 'name(/a/*)' -
```

but this only gives me `b`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think an XPath 1.0 expression can do it, you either need XPath 2.0 `/a/*/name()` (which I don't think xmlstarlet supports) or you need to use XSLT or try to use the xmlstarlet command line options to try to mimic XSLT. I don't have access to that tool and I am not familiar with details, according to http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt you could try

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/a/*" -v "name()"
```

Untested.

Comment: Yes, this works well! If I add an -n flag, I even get the line breaks:
`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/a/*" -n -v "name()"`